# How to get contacts in children of a parent group using the API

Tags: contacts, api, groups

I have a child groups C and B, each with 20 different contacts in them. Both child groups are in parent group A. I need to find all contacts in all children of A since C and B might be removed later or new children added to A. But A will not change. However, Group A is not *itself* populated. As a result, the CiviCRM API returns 0 results. Is there handy API method which will help me out?

API Command:

```
 $result = civicrm_api3('GroupContact', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'group_id' => "Donors_74",
));
```

Actual results from the API explorer:

```
{
"is_error": 0,
"version": 3,
"count": 0,
"values": [

    ]
}
```

Expected result: 1676

[image]

We are using CiviCRM 4.7.25.

Comment: What API command are you running that is returning 0 results?

Comment: I have updated my question with the API command

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'group' filter on the Contact api to get members of parent groups.

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'group' => XX,
  'options' => array('limit' => 0),
));
```

where XX is the id of the parent group (A).

Comment: Unfortunately, that causes the error Uncaught CiviCRM_API3_Exception: [no such field: DB Error: no such field.

Comment: Are you using the id or the name?  It's working for me with the numeric id, but the name produces an error.

Answer (score 0):

The query worked fine for me, i am using name of group instead of id. Example:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'group' => "Advisory Board",
  'options' => array('limit' => 0),
));
```